# displaying image from sqlite error

Tags: qt, qt4, qpixmap

I have saved an image in sqlite and i am trying to retrieve it and displaying it in a QLabel using this code.

```
connect(ui.tableView->selectionModel(), SIGNAL(currentRowChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)),
                this, SLOT(getImage(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)));


void smith::getImage()
{
    .......
    QModelIndex index = ui.tableView->currentIndex();
    QString sqlQuery = QString("SELECT image FROM %1 WHERE id=:id").arg(tableName);
    query.prepare(sqlQuery);
    QSqlRecord recordz = tableModel->record(index.row());
    query.bindValue(":id", recordz.value("id").toInt());
    query.exec();
    tableModel->select();

    QByteArray array = query.value(0).toByteArray();
    QBuffer buffer(&array);
    buffer.open( QIODevice::ReadOnly );

    QImageReader reader(&buffer, "PNG");
    QImage image = reader.read();

if( image.isNull() )
{
    QMessageBox::about(this, tr("Image Is Null"),
                       tr("<h2>Image Error</h2>"
                          "<p>Copyright &copy; 2011."
                          "<p>Message Box To Check For  "
                          " Errors "
                          ));
}
    ui.imageLabel->setPixmap( QPixmap::fromImage(image));

}
```

The project compiles without any errors but the image won't show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest adding some error-checking to your code, to narrow down where the error occurs.

For example, the documentation for [`QImageReader::read()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qimagereader.html#read) says that if the image can't be read, the resultant image is null, and it tells you how to find out what the error was.

So after your call to `reader.read()`, check `image.isNull()`.

And earlier on, check `array.size()` to make sure that you really got a value back from the database.

And the check the result returned by `buffer.open( QIODevice::ReadOnly )` - the docs say it will return `false` if the call failed.

Comment: I edited to include image.isNull() and no error there it seems.

Comment: That's odd. I've just written a little program with a `QLabel` and calling `label->setPixmap( QPixmap::fromImage(image));` puts in image on the label, just fine. (I copied the setPixmap call direcctly from your code)

Comment: Is it possible to have Qt::UniqueConnection in connect(ui.tableView->selectionModel(), SIGNAL(currentRowChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)),
                this, SLOT(getImage(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)));?

Comment: I've no idea, I'm afraid. I know about images and labels, but not database connections! As you found your image isn't null, I'd suggest focussing on whether the image itself is actually valid, and contains the actual image you wanted to extract from the database.

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer